# CSS overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a container div.  Inside that div are three graphs aligned at 700px intervals (the width of the container).  The idea is that the other 2 graphs will be hidden off screen which I can then, with jQuery, slide across when a user interacts with various controls on the web page.

A simplified version of my code is like so:

Style

```
    #graphcontainer {
        height: 260px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 700px;
    }
    .graph {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="graphcontainer">
        <div class="graph" style="left: 0px;"></div>
        <div class="graph" style="left: 700px;"></div>
        <div class="graph" style="left: 1400px;"></div>
</div>
```

For some reason the second and third graphs, which are positioned off to the right, are still visible! How do I ensure they are not visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to set, `position:relative` for the parent. Then, you have to set the height of the parent.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Scfdk/

Comment: Thanks this worked, thanks also for the jsfiddle link it helped

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `position: relative;` and set a height to the element you have overflow set to hidden on.

Comment: I don't think that setting only `position:relative` will solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I noticed and was about to edit my post although you already posted including the height of the parent element. Thank you.

Comment: I had actually already set height (I omitted it as I didnt think it was necessary). +1 for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide a div, have you considered "display: none"?  For example,
`<div class="graph" style="display: none"/>`

Comment: I usually do this but as I want to animate the graphs sliding around I cannot use `display`